# Eclipse configured tomcat doesn't delete server restart changes

Tags: tomcat6, eclipse-3.6

I have a spring based maven web project on eclipse 3.6 and a locally configured tomcat 6 with it. When I make changes in any java source file or any configuration file it doesn't ask me to restart the server when I look at the tomcat instance.

Earlier for any server side changes it used to show a sign Restart at the tomcat server. Now I have to clean the project every time before a server restart to make the changes take effect.

So [this](http://img403.imageshack.us/img403/6561/republish.jpg)[Started/Republish] is what it shows after making server side changes while [this](http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/8533/restartp.jpg)[Started/Restart] is how it should be. But [Started/Restart] doesn't happen automatically and I have to clean the project everytime for it.

Help needed.

Thanks.

EDIT: [This](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/3324/tomcatm.jpg) is the tomcat configuration I have. I also have  **Build Automatically** checked on the **Project**.

Answer (score 0):

Make enable class file of the file in which you make change for tomcat server. More explanation is required on question ,i guess.

Comment: I have edited the post by adding the screen shot of my tomcat configuration. Could you please tell me what did you mean by "Make enable class file of the file in which you make change for tomcat server." I am sorry I couldn't get it.